# Printing: visibility:none elements take up space somehow and result in empty pages

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a webpage with a print button

```
onClick="window.print()"
```

I have a css stylesheet, which hides all elements that should not be displayed when printing (using display:none). Example:

```
@media print
{
.gf-menu {display:none;}
}
```

Actual content only takes one page of space. Sidebar takes 3 pages of space (what, its a big sidebar, sue me). The sidebar is not displayed when printing (display:none;), but it seems that it still takes up space.

Result is that I have 1 page of content and 2 pages of empty space. How can I remove that space?
I tried to manually set height of body when printing but it had no effect. Is there any way I can remove/prevent the extra pages?